# Scale bitmap in SurfaceView

Tags: android, scale, surfaceview

This is my code for in the `Sprite` class:

```
public class Sprite {
    int x, y, vx, vy;
    private Bitmap texture;

    public Sprite(Bitmap texture) {
        this.texture = texture;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return texture.getWidth();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return texture.getHeight();
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c) {
        c.drawBitmap(texture, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

and with `background.draw(c);` I draw a background. But the background is bigger than the screen...

How can I scale it to the size of the screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting only the left and top properties of the bitmap when drawing it. To scale it, call an overload drawBitmap method with width and height, [like this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

To give you the idea:

```
public class Sprite {
    int width, height;
    private Bitmap texture;

    public Sprite(Bitmap texture, width, height) {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c) {
        c.drawBitmap(texture, null, new RectF(0, 0, width, height), null);
    }
}
```

In the Activity where you create the class Sprite you must do something like:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(bitmap, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight())
```

Comment: when i dont want colors do i have to write `null` there?

Comment: You can use the method: public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint) and pass it null for src if you want no clipping, and create a dst rectangle that defines the area where the bitmap will be drawn (its left top corner will set the left top corner of the bitmap and its width and hight will set the bitmap's width and height)

Comment: and how do i get the screen size?

Comment: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); and then use display.getWidth() and display.getHeight()

Comment: it say "create method `getWindowManager()`"

Comment: You must call getWindowManager from the activity, then you can pass the width and height of the display to your class.

Comment: how can i pass it? :( sry I really dont know how

Comment: You could add two parameters width and height to your Sprite class constructor (like: public Sprite(Bitmap texture, int width, int height)). In your Activity class you could write something like: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(bitmap, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());

Comment: the problem is, that I create the class Sprite in a thread and not an activity.. so I can't use getWindowManager there too...

Comment: hmm, ok then since you pass a Canvas to the Sprite's draw method, you can stretch the bitmap to the size of that canvas. You can use c.getWidth() and c.GetHeight().

Comment: hmm but I create the class before the canvas is loaded :D

Comment: Yes, you create the sprite class, but you draw the sprite after the canvas is created, because you will pass the canvas to the sprite, so the sprite can draw itself on it. So you know the size of the canvas when you call draw().